# Swagger Ui forcing input as File upload type instead of Text

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

I have an endpoint to save some data. I mapped the input json to a class with name `File`.

```
@PutMapping(path = "/file")
public boolean save(@RequestBody File file) {
   // logic
}
```

When hooked up with swagger, the swagger ui considers this as a file type input.

[image]

How can I force the value on swagger ui to consider it as a regular text instead of a file upload?

Expected:

[image]

I tried :

```
@PutMapping(path = "/file", consumes = "application/json")
```

Comment: `public boolean save(@RequestBody String file)`

Comment: But I'd like to have it as a custom File datatype. Is it conflicting with swagger ui?

Comment: I don't know any way to do it